# Redefinition error while accessing a global variable defined in executable from library

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ubuntu-16.04

I have static library file(`lib_XXX.a`) with global variable defined in it. I am trying to access the global variable in my executable(`exe_XXX.o`).
Linker error is coming. Any help would be thankful.

```
Languae : c
OS : Ubuntu gcc compiler
```

Sample as follows

`exe_xxx.o` module has 2 files `resource.h` and `main.c`

`resource.h` code as follows :

```
#ifndef RESOURCE_H
#define RESOURCE_H

#define APL

extern const StructTest g_AplObjDef;

const StructTest g_AplObjDef = {
abc, def, ghi,
....
};

#endif //APL
```

`main.c` code as follows:

```
#include "resource.h"
....
....
....
```

`lib_xxx.a` has another `main.c` in it. Its sample code as follows:

```
#include "resource.h"

int main()
{
#if defined(APL)
     fun1(g_AplObjDef);
#endif
}
```

I suspect the reason is because `resource.h` included in both the `main.c` files.
I couldn't way to get rid of this. Can anyone help ?

Error details:
/lib_XXX.a(lib_XXX_a-main.o):(.data.rel.ro.local+0x40): `g_AplObjDef' が重複して定義されています
/exe_xxx-main.o:(.data.rel.ro.local+0x260): ここで最初に定義されています

Above error is in Japanese.. 1st line says "Duplicate is defined". 2nd line says "Here it is defined"

Comment: I don't see you quoting the error verbatim, in full and as text.

Comment: You are defining a variable in the header, should only declare.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have two `main()` ? Or is just the file name misleading me?

Comment: To only declare change this `const StructTest g_AplObjDef` to `extern const StructTest g_AplObjDef;`. Then move the defining part into a/the code file.

Comment: Is there a specail reason for trying to define `main()` inside the lib instead of in the main.c? I am not used to that.

Comment: Please provide a translation of the error to English, ideally try to provoke an English error which you can quote here.

Comment: Please create a [mre], that will allow making a more helpful answer than my comments (or the recent answer below....).

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks.. YES i need 2 main... One is in lib and another is in exe....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part:

```
const StructTest g_AplObjDef = {
    abc, def, ghi,
    ....
};
```

is a definition, and should not be in a header. Move it to
a `.c` file.

The reason for this is that header files are textually inserted, so if a header has a definition, and is included from multiple translation units, the symbol will be defined multiple times, which is an error.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my comment. For an answer I would expect a solution proposal however...

Comment: I appreciate that you edited to provide a solution proposal. Would you however like to make the additional insight more obvious which you provide when compared to my previously existing comments? Without the OP providing more information I expect you cannot do anything more than I did, but that would of course make for a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are defining a variable in the header

```
 const StructTest g_AplObjDef =
```

You should only declare, which you did the line before.
This definition should go into a code file, accessing it will be possible by the knowledge provded by the declaration in the header. But the definition in the header will be done in each code file which includes it, which causes the redundant definition mentioned in the error message.

Moving the definition (as you now have it in the header, including the `{...}` into the libs code file should help.

Note that having two `main()` will probably get you into trouble, I only focus this answer on the double definition of the variable.